# Express app can't GET static content when changing NginX location block

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, gulp

I have an express.js AngularJs application that uses gulp for building and serving different environments (namely dev/staging/testing/production) and NginX as a reverse proxy.

## The NodeJS App

The application has been written following John Papa's AngularJS styleguide and the gulp configuration is heavily inspired by [this sample application of his](https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/tree/master/modular).

The **essential** parts of the application is structured in the following way:

```
/build  (created on the fly, optimizes code)
/src (no optimiztion)
    /client
        /app
        /content
        /test
        index.html
    /server
        /data
        /routes
gulpfile.js
```

#### Express Middleware Excerpt

```
// /src/server/app.js
switch (environment){
    case 'stage':
    case 'build':
        console.log('** BUILD **');
        console.log('serving from ' + './build/');           
        app.use('/', express.static('./build/'));
        break;
    default:
        console.log('** DEV **');
        console.log('serving from ' + './src/client/ and ./');
        app.use('/', express.static('./src/client/'));
        app.use('/', express.static('./'));
        break;  
}

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
    console.log('env = ' + app.get('env') +
        '\n__dirname = ' + __dirname  +
        '\nprocess.cwd = ' + process.cwd());
});
```

## Reverse Proxy

I'm using NginX as a reverse proxy for the express server and can access it at *my_domain_name* using the configuration below.

```
upstream my_nodejs_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:7203;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_domain_name;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
}
```

**This works**, but I ultimately want to be able to access the app at *my_domain_name/app* so I thought that simply changing the location URI would do the trick.

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
}
```

**This doesn't work**. I'm able to access the app via the express server, i.e. at my_domain_name:7203, but trying to access it at my_domain_name/app I'm receiving 404 errors on all static content. It seems like the "/app/" portion doesn't get passed on. For example, requesting the minified CSS is still being done at *https://my_domain_name/content/all.min-06c3b402.css* whereas the file at this point is located at *https://my_domain_name/app/content/all.min-06c3b402.css*.

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here.

## Edit 1 (2018-03-01)

Omitting the `/`, i.e. `proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream;` still works if I put in the `location /` block, but not in `location /app`. I'm running into a different error this time however as I'm not able to access the it at all: `Cannot GET /app`. I also updated the OP with some additional info (namely the **Express Middleware Excerpt** section).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx proxy config not forwarding requests to backend server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273312/nginx-proxy-config-not-forwarding-requests-to-backend-server)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
```

I'm pretty sure you should write:

```
proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream;
```

without the ending `/`. That ending `/` is an url, and [proxy_pass directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) does not behaves the same way if you give it an url or not (bold added) :

> If the **proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI**, then when a request
>   is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching
>   the location is **replaced** by a URI specified in the directive
>   (...)

vs

> If **proxy_pass is specified without a URI**, the request URI is passed to 
>   the server **in the same form** as sent by a client when the original request
>   is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when
>   processing the changed URI
>   (...)

Other solutions may imply using capture of location and reusing it on the proxy_pass directive, or adding `$request_uri` on this proxy_pass rewrite, but I do not think you need it here.

Comment: Okay, I see. That totally makes sense. The proxy still works when placed under location/, but I'm running into "Cannot GET /app" when placing it under location/app. Made some changes in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and I solved it by changing the path on express, instead of responding to `app.get("/")` I passed the name of the location on nginx, in your case should be `app.get("/app")`.

Comment: were you able to serve your stylesheets as well - after changing the express route? I am able to serve locally but not via nginx app.use(express.static('public')); // Set Express paths
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use('/dev',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); none of this middleware worked